# Regex to pick up the third folder name from the end

Tags: regex

I have been stuck on this one for sometime. I need to select the third folder from the end of a path.

If this is the path:

C:\ColorBank\User\Profiles\Shades\bin\debug

I want to extract third one from the end.

e.g. Shades.

What I have come up with is this.

```
[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$
```

But it is also picking up the last two, e.g. it is returning me: Shades\bin\debug

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use lookahead so that it won't match the first and second part from the last.

```
[^\\]*(?=\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/3)

OR

```
[^\\]+(?=\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/4)

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. I will study up on Lookahead. Seems to be key to almost all regex problems I am having.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to capture that text?

You can do this with non-greedy quantifiers (add `?` after the `+`). Result: the folder name (in your example, the word `Shades`) will be stored in `$1` or `\1` depending on your environment...

```
([^\\]+?)\\[^\\]+?\\[^\\]+?$
```

Answer (score 0):

here is more of a dynamic answer where you could easily adjust to get the n-th occurrence

```
([^\\]+)(?=(?:\\[^\\]+){2}$)
```

where 2 = n-1
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gX3fX0/4)